# ERROR in DIV background does't cover vertical menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `bootstrap.css` and `<div class="box">/''HTML content'''/</div>`

- class=box is div box with white background
- I have vertical menu inside `<div class="box">/''vertical menu''/</div>`

When run the page I don't get the div box covering the full vertical menu.

### div box CSS

```
.box {
padding: 50px 30px;
background: #fff;
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;}
```

and i have added  `<div id="leftmenu">` inside box

### leftmenu css

```
#leftmenu {
margin-left: 100px;
float: left;
width: 25%;
}
```

and am listing two div in same row 2 div in same row works but div box does't cover the 2 div

error
div box does't cover the vertical menu

## [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanoj908572/t1kovnvo/)

Comment: try this - http://jsfiddle.net/9gLeL6gc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the `.box` class like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ndsmqkqy/)**

```
.box {
    padding: 50px 30px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**OR:** place your `<div style="clear:both"></div>` inside the `<div class="box"></div>` - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zawtsomu/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can add `float:left; width:100%;` to your code.

```
.box {
padding: 50px 30px;
background: #fff;
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;
float:left;
width:100%;
```

}

JsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t1kovnvo/2/).